# Python script to find the rows which are not common

Tags: python

I have two files as follows, the  first objective is to get the rows which are not common among  1.csv and 2.csv by comparing the first columns first 14 digits.

Second objective is if the first column in 1.csv is matching with any of the first columns in 2.csv, compare the same rows second column with that of the second column of 1.csv  and print the row which is not present in 1.csv and present in 2.csv

The script is below as follow but not able to get the desired output

```
import csv
t1 = open('1.csv', 'r')
t2 = open('2.csv', 'r')
fileone = t1.readlines()
filetwo = t2.readlines()
t1.close()
t2.close()

outFile = open('update.csv', 'w')
x = 0
for i in fileone:
    if i != filetwo[x]:
        outFile.write(filetwo[x])
    x += 1
outFile.close()
```

Comment: The proper tool to do so is pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0):

If the format is given fixed it would be a solution to split each line into 2 pieces so you can compare only the first 14 digits as you requested.

The solution you have does only a line by line comparison. If you split up the lines you can iterate over data of either of the files and use simple 'in' to see if the line is in the other file.

Answer (score 0):

First thing always use `with` when handling files, it will take one line less and will never forget to close the files:

```
with open('1.csv', 'r') as file1, open('2.csv', 'r') as file2:
    file1_lines = file1.readlines()
    file2_lines = file2.readlines()

file1_headers = [line[:14] for line in file1_lines]
file2_headers = [line[:14] for line in file2_lines]

with open('update.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    # Objective 1: lines that have their first 14 digit in one file only
    for line in file1_lines:
        if line[:14] not in file2_headers:
            out_file.write(line)
    for line in file2_lines:
        if line[:14] not in file1_headers:
            out_file.write(line)
    # Objective 2: Lines that are in file 2 but not 1
    for line in file2_lines:
        if line not in file1_lines:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Your code doesn't mention `14` anywhere, that should alert you in the first place ;-) cheers!

Comment: python 4.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.py", line 4, in <module>
    file1_lines = fh1.readlines()
NameError: name 'fh1' is not defined

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but there is needs a one more logic, one row first coloumnin 1.csv  and one of the first row in 2.csv are the same, but the second coloumn is different. i want the 2.csv row to be printed in the output

Comment: You need to explain more the logic of 14 first digit, please read again your question and update it, also put more clear example input and output so I can help

Comment: because the first 14 digit are the same in 1.csv and 2.csv : 22222222222222 that's what your question wants, please modify if not the case

Comment: in my question my second objective was that.. please have a look

Comment: I edited my code, if it does not work for you please edit your question to be more explicit and if it works please upvote and validate